# Reading files via Samba slower after Ubuntu upgrade to 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, samba

Before the upgrade opening the file via a log reader (in this case BareTail) on Windows machine via **Samba** would show the update for the file every second.

Linux machine is upgraded to **Ubuntu 16.04** same **Samba** configuration file used. After this my log reader opens the file and updates are shown every 15 seconds or so.

What could have the upgrade changed that I am seeing this?

Comment: Does this only happen for folders created after the upgrade?
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2354718

Comment: @Tommy No. This was (probably still is) in general for all the files.